# What is a mutli-bit port (4-bit, 8-bit, ..etc.)

Tags: datasheet, port, pins

I've been researching XMOS multicore microcontrollers lately so that I can use them soon.  I've worked with many development boards, even made a few of my own, although there is one thing that I don't understand about their controllers.

When they discuss the pin descriptions of any controller, they describe some as being 1-bit, and others being 4-bit or 8-bit or something.  How can they be multi-bit? I thought that if the pin was digital, it is 1-bit because of its nature.

Apologies,  I didn't give the actual datasheet. Here:
https://www.xmos.com/en/download/public/XS1-L16A-128-QF124-Datasheet%28X8006F%29.pdf

on page 6

Comment: Can you give a link to where you read about these things? Some context would help us make sure we give you an appropriate answer.

Comment: That said, an 8-bit port is normally 8 pins that are controlled by a single register or otherwise work together to provide a full byte of I/O.

Comment: I added the datasheet into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably referring to a "port" as something that gives you access to a collection of related pins.  The port is usually mapped into data memory so that all of it can be accessed together as one word.  Individual bits in that port will map to individual pins.  Most likely there are ways to accessing the individual bits in the port word, thereby given you access to individual pins.

Comment: yup! turns out its just 4-bit is 4 different pins all mapped to different bits of a port register.  same with 32-bit and all that.  Thanks!